# How do I correctly write out this intimidating looking summation?

Tags: summation, notation

How do I write out the following equation:

$\Delta S = \sqrt{\sum_{a=\alpha,\alpha'}^{}\sum_{b=\beta,\beta'}^{}\Delta E(a,b)^2}$

I guess what's throwing me off here is:

I) there is no upper bound on either sigma

II) I don't know how to interpret a notation such as $a=\alpha,\alpha'$

Answer (score 2):

In general, the notation
$$\sum_{P(x)}f(x)$$
usually means the sum of $f(x)$ for values of $x$ where $P(x)$ is true. So for your case,
$$\sum_{a=\alpha,\alpha'}\sum_{b=\beta,\beta'}\Delta E(a,b)^2=\Delta E(\alpha,\beta)^2+\Delta E(\alpha',\beta)^2+\Delta E(\alpha,\beta’)^2+\Delta E(\alpha',\beta')^2$$
is probably the intended meaning.

Comment: Thank you! So could $a=\alpha,\alpha'$ be interpreted as "$a$ is either $\alpha$ or $\alpha'$"?

Comment: @YaelLandman: Yes, I would say so.